# How to shift the alignment of text in a select dropdown toward the top and left with CSS?

Tags: html, css, select, html-select

I'm trying to display a dropdown over top of a spreadsheet-like table with JavaScript and CSS but am having issues with the alignment.  I've set all borders, margins and paddings to zero, however I have been unable to determine how to move the text (the default text, prior to a drop-down list being displayed) toward the top-left corner.  I've used `text-indent: -3px;` to get it to move left, but there is `3px-5px` gap (clearly visible with `background-color: #888888;` and not just the edge of the select's boundaries) that clips the text on the left.

Does anyone know how to shift the text position of a select-based HTML dropdown to the top-left?

Edit:

Adding computed styles from Chrome to demonstate the difference between a text box and a dropdown with screenshot.

Textbox CSS:

```
-webkit-border-image: none;
-webkit-line-break: after-white-space;
-webkit-nbsp-mode: space;
-webkit-user-modify: read-write;
border-bottom-color: rgb(37, 66, 100);
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-color: rgb(37, 66, 100);
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: rgb(37, 66, 100);
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: rgb(37, 66, 100);
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
color: rgb(37, 66, 100);
cursor: auto;
display: block;
font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
height: 18px;
left: 204px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
outline-color: rgb(37, 66, 100);
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
position: absolute;
top: 21px;
white-space: pre;
width: 73px;
word-wrap: break-word;
z-index: 99;
```

Select CSS:

```
-webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
-webkit-border-image: none;
-webkit-box-align: center;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-bottom-color: rgb(37, 66, 100);
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-color: rgb(37, 66, 100);
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: rgb(37, 66, 100);
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: rgb(37, 66, 100);
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(37, 66, 100);
cursor: default;
display: block;
font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
height: 16px;
left: 281px;
letter-spacing: normal;
line-height: normal;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
outline-color: rgb(37, 66, 100);
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
position: absolute;
text-align: start;
text-indent: -3px;
text-shadow: none;
text-transform: none;
top: 22px;
white-space: pre;
width: 135px;
word-spacing: 0px;
writing-mode: lr-tb;
z-index: 99;
```

Screenshot of textbox:
[image]
Screenshot of select:
[image]

Comment: Any code to show ? jsfiddle ?

Comment: I edited the post to show the CSS used and a screenshot of the issue.

Comment: Is the text wrapped by a `<span>`?

Comment: No, the text which is having difficulties is in the <select> tag (the second screenshot).

Comment: css only is not enough. Html-css layout becomes capricious in too many ways (browser, doctype, validity, javascript interference) to just 'pinpoint' your situation with a solution. Can you provide a working example ? If you google 'chrome html select bug' you'll understand that i need the whole html context to help you. https://www.google.ca/search?num=100&hl=fr&newwindow=1&q=chrome+html+select+bug

Comment: The code would be difficult to condense into an example accurately - it is spread over about 10 different JS and CSS files and I can't just pull it from the page because it's all created via the DOM.  The issue is moving the position of selected text within an HTML <select> to the upper-left, if it is possible there should be a way to move it well outside the bounds of the <select> itself if desired, 'text-align', 'vertical-align', etc aren't the type of answer I'm looking for - more the equivalent of 'left' and 'top' for the selected item text within a <select>.  See second screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same exact situation as you... Sadly the only thing I could come up with that helped align the text a little more properly was adding: `&nbsp;`

```
<select name='something'>
<option value='nan'>&nbsp;&nbsp; Some Text Here</option>
<option value='nan'>&nbsp;&nbsp; Some Text Here</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the same conclusion I came to.  Ended up rolling my own dropdown that can be styled since I needed a few other things anyway (paging through hundreds of thousands of items without being slow, multi-select functionality, hierarchial listings, etc).  The dropdown is definitely an irritating control.

Answer (score 1):

Just to rule out the basics, have you tried:

```
   option, select {
      text-align: left;
      vertical-align: top;
   }
```

Comment: Yes, I've already tried that.  I ended up creating a pseudoclass that spawns a select inside a div, with a div over top of the text area containing a background-color to block the text, then a contenteditable div aligned over that - I needed the option of adding items to the select by editing the text in it anyway, still would have preferred a less hackey method though - it's amazing how little HTML controls have evolved over the years.  Damn near everyone needs treeviews, multi-column lists, multi-select or editable dropdowns, etc at some point, yet are forced to hack them together.